# How does one select all child components (not DOM elements) used in a Reactjs component template?

Tags: reactjs

I have a situation where I have two elements that are tied together, with a Board that non-negotiably always consists of 4 subdivision panels:

```
var BoardPanel = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { someval: '' };
  }, 
  render: function() {
    <div>{this.state.someval}</div>
  },
  doSomething: function(v) {
    setState({ someval: v });
  }
});

var BoardLayout = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    <div>
      <h1>{this.props.label{</h1>
      <div ref="panels">
        <BoardPanel />
        <BoardPanel />
        <BoardPanel />
        <BoardPanel />
      </div>
    </div>
  }
});
```

The BoardLayout should be able to uniformly tell each BoardPanel to call panel API functions, so I would like to do the React.js equivalent of:

```
this.querySelectorAll("BoardPanel")
    .array()
    .forEach(function(panel, idx) {
       panel.doSomething(idx);
    });
```

Note that I expressly **do not** want to access the DOM nodes here, I want to access the React-defined virtual elements, call functions on that, and never ever touch the actual browser-used DOM.

I had a look at the React.children utility functions, but these are fairly useless because there is no way to specify which children I want, and `this.props.children` is going to give me two `div` elements, since the `BoardPanel` elements live "deep" inside the template.

(I'm also fairly averse to adding `ref="..."` with throwaway identifiers for each BoardPanel, because there shouldn't be any need to do this, given that this is well formatted, structured markup. It's a possible workaround, but seems about as sensible as slapping ids on every element in an HTML file instead of relying on query selectors)

I could dynamically generate them by not actually having them in the template at all and adding them using `React.create(BoardPanel)` in `BoardLayout.getInitialState` but that would turn the immediately insightful template structure into an opaque placeholder, which is also a thing I'd rather not do.

Can I, in `BoardLayout.componentDidMount` or the like, somehow get the array of `BoardPanel` components used, so that I can directly instruct those components to do things? If so, how?

Comment: This is typically handled by passing a prop to each BoardPanel that will effect whatever change is needed when the source data changes.

Comment: If `BoardPanel` should react to specific changes that it makes sense for it to know about, it can inspect incoming props in [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) and make changes internally before the update occurs.

Comment: they're not just props though, some actions "on the board" requires each panel to do a thing, local to itself, similar to in plain JS you'd have a `boardlayout.querySelector("boardpanel").array().forEach(function(panel) { panel.reset(); });` (there's a number of calls that take no arguments, so for which prop-sparking doesn't make all that much sense, at least conceptually)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to do this (you probably don't), you need to use refs.

```
function refsToArray(ctx, prefix){
  var results = [];
  for (var i=0;;i++){
    var ref = ctx.refs[prefix + '-' + String(i)];
    if (ref) results.push(ref);
    else return results;
  }
}

var BoardLayout = React.createClass({
  var makeRef = function(){ return 'BoardPanel-'+(_refi++); }, _refi=0;
  render: function() {
    <div>
      <h1>{this.props.label{</h1>
      <div ref="panels">
        <BoardPanel ref={makeRef()} />
        <BoardPanel ref={makeRef()} />
        <BoardPanel ref={makeRef()} />
        <BoardPanel ref={makeRef()} />
      </div>
    </div>
  }
});
```

And then you would do `refsToArray(this, 'BoardPanel')` to get an array of refs.

But like I said, there's probably a better solution but you didn't indicate what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: the post was pretty much what I'm actually trying to do. I have a game board with four panels (it's a four player game), and depending on actions "on the game board" all player panels need to perform identical operations. I'm using refs atm, and that works fine, but also feels like I'm writing too much code for what should be discoverable from the structure itself.

Comment: That sounds like you should be using an event emitter, passing it to the BoardPanel components as a prop, and letting them subscribe to various events themselves.

Comment: That sounds like the ideal solution! Is that part of plain React, though? A quick google reveals a ton of flux examples, which I'm not making use of.

Comment: If you're using browserify/webpack `new (require('events').EventEmitter)` will give you an emitter with .on/.off/.removeListener.  Otherwise you can get a [standalone version of 'events'](http://wzrd.in/standalone/events).  Then `new events.EventEmitter()` will give you the event emitter.

Comment: nice. If you want to update the answer, I'll hit the check mark.